# One interface for different generic classes

Tags: java, generics, interface

I am having a bit trouble with generics in Java because I am not sure if what I am trying to achieve actually exists.

I wrote the following class (simplified here, without getter/setter):

```
public class Pair<T>{
  public T firstEntry;
  public T secondEntry;

  public Pair(T p_First, T p_Second) {
      this.m_First = p_First;
      this.m_Second = p_Second;
  }
}
```

Now I want actually the same class but with the possibility that firstEntry and secondEntry can be of different type. For example some class like this:

```
public class PairMultipleType<T, K>{
  public T firstEntry;
  public K secondEntry;

  public Pair(T p_First, K p_Second) {
      this.m_First = p_First;
      this.m_Second = p_Second;
  }
}
```

But I want to use the classes like this:

```
Pair<Integer> myPair = new Pair<Integer>(a, b); //Creates pair with one type.
Pair<Integer, String> myPair = new Pair<Integer, String>(a, "Hallo Welt"); //Creates pair with two types.
```

I am aware that this code would be wrong anyways because the classes may not have the same name. But that is the point: Is it possible to write an interface to which I can use to achieve the desired behaviour? If it is possible, how can it be done?

Comment: I would use `Pair<SomeClass, SomeClass>` instead. Otherwise, you could extend your `Pair<T, K>` with another `SingleTypePair<T> extends Pair<T, T>` but I won't rely on this design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't declare your `Pair` variables (or the class itself) to have a variable number of type parameters.

But what you could do is have `Pair` extend `PairMultipleType`, but define its only type parameter to be both parameters of `PairMultipleType`.

```
public class Pair<T> extends PairMultipleType<T, T> {
    public Pair(T p_First, T p_Second) {
        super(p_First, p_Second);
    }
}
```

Be careful with this design, because it's easy to mix up your generic type parameters.  But you can do this:

```
Pair<String> pair = new Pair<String>("one", "two");
PairMultipleType<String, String> pair2 = new Pair<String>("one", "two");
PairMultipleType<Integer, String> pair3 = new PairMultipleType<Integer, String>(1, "one");
```

Comment: I think the issue is more along the lines of "overloading" the `Pair` class with different type parameters as opposed to using it with a variable number of type parameters. (P.S. I didn't downvote.)

Comment: @arshajii The OP states "But I want to use the classes like this:" and then uses `Pair` with a variable number of type parameters.  Besides, your solution is equivalent to mine, just with different class names.

Comment: The fact I don't recommend this is because a `SingleTypePair` may not be always a `Pair`, similar to a `Square` and `Rectangle` example in Liskov substitution principle.

Comment: Thank you. I think both answers do actually the same in the end. But I marked your respond as answer because I like the way the class can be used more.

Answer (score 4):

What you're trying to do is not allowed due to [type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html). The suggestion made in the comments is a good alternative: have a `Pair<T,K>` base class and have an extending `SingleTypePair<T>` class.

```
class Pair<T, K> {
    protected T firstEntry;
    protected K secondEntry;

    public Pair(T firstEntry, K secondEntry) {
        this.firstEntry = firstEntry;
        this.secondEntry = secondEntry;
    }
}

class SingleTypePair<T> extends Pair<T, T> {

    public SingleTypePair(T firstEntry, T secondEntry) {
        super(firstEntry, secondEntry);
    }
}
```